# Multiple Filter Criteria -Excel Table

Tags: office-js, power-automate, office-scripts

I am trying to filter the following table with multiple Criteria which are passed from PowerAutomate. I want to filter the Product column for *"Product-1", "Product-3", "Product-5",* Location column for *"East", "West"* and Colour column for *"Black", "White"*.

I am passing three variable from Power-Automate to office script as *product_Name* , *product_Location* and *product_Color*.
Where

product_Name = "Product-1", "Product-3", "Product-5"

product_Location = "East", "West"

product_Color="Black", "White"

I am using the following office script to apply the filter, however with this the filter can not be applied as it in only filtering the column as "Product-1", "Product-3", "Product-5" not a row specific.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook,
    product_Name?: string,
    product_Location?: string,
    product_Color?: string,
) {
    let table2 = workbook.getTable("Table2");
    // Apply checked items filter on table table2 column Product
    table2.getColumnByName("Product").getFilter().applyValuesFilter([product_Name]);

    // Apply checked items filter on table table2 column Location
    table2.getColumnByName("Location").getFilter().applyValuesFilter([product_Location]);

    // Apply checked items filter on table table2 column Color
    table2.getColumnByName("Color").getFilter().applyValuesFilter([product_Color]);
}
```

*Table:*

| Product | Location | Colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product-1 | East | Black |
| Product-2 | West | Red |
| Product-3 | South | Blue |
| Product-4 | West | Blue |
| Product-5 | East | Yellow |
| Product-1 | West | White |
| Product-2 | East | Black |
| Product-3 | West | Red |
| Product-4 | South | Blue |
| Product-5 | West | Blue |
| Product-1 | East | Yellow |
| Product-2 | West | White |
| Product-3 | South | Black |
| Product-4 | West | Red |
| Product-5 | South | Blue |
| Product-1 | West | Blue |
| Product-2 | East | Yellow |
| Product-3 | West | White |

how can I use the variables as proper filter? Can any one help on this ?

Comment: Can you console.log the value of the three product variables you listed in your OP? I'd like to see if they're strings and, if so, what they look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`applyValuesFilter` takes an array of strings as a parameter. The simplest way you could do this is by changing your parameter to an array of strings -

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook,
    product_Names?: string[],
    product_Locations?: string[],
    product_Colors?: string[],
) {
    let table2 = workbook.getTable("Table2");
    // Apply checked items filter on table table2 column Product
    table2.getColumnByName("Product").getFilter().applyValuesFilter(product_Names);

    // Apply checked items filter on table table2 column Location
    table2.getColumnByName("Location").getFilter().applyValuesFilter(product_Locations);

    // Apply checked items filter on table table2 column Color
    table2.getColumnByName("Color").getFilter().applyValuesFilter(product_Colors);
}
```

The values for Power Automate would have to be changed to arrays as well

product_Name = **[**"Product-1", "Product-3", "Product-5"**]**

product_Location = **[**"East", "West"**]**

product_Color= **[**"Black", "White"**]**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in Columns A-C and your sheet name is Sheet1,

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let sheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");

    let table = sheet.getTable("Table2");
    table.getAutoFilter().apply("A1", 0, { filterOn: ExcelScript.FilterOn.values, values: ["Product-1", "Product-3", "Product-5"] });

    table.getAutoFilter().apply("B1", 1, { filterOn: ExcelScript.FilterOn.values, values: ["East", "West"] });

    table.getAutoFilter().apply("C1", 2, { filterOn: ExcelScript.FilterOn.values, values: ["Black", "White"] });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, is there a way I can pass the values using any variable? I need this as I will be fetching the variables from power automate to this script.

Comment: @NavonilSaha let values= table.getRange().getVisibleView().getValues();